# Flex requests by URLLoader not being well received on server side

Tags: actionscript-3, web-services, apache-flex, networking, urlencode

today's question involves URLLoader requests using encrypted strings.

when I encrypt a string I get the following result:

```
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
```

I send it in, everything seems fine on Flex's end. But when I go to the serverside (logfiles, not allowed to change server-side code) to check what I'm getting, I end up with this:

```
1Kx4dfp5OC7ox0zb0lWzzzlnoPLcoPGE1MrAKOtl3h6SPcFmEdpLnUROSKpPrCl70VHRxrKzhsxHHlb1MRp3  JkvYZ  ghBEG2zbVhyaqQ/0 NDrJ 0cLt3g9THe9POohN6Ufcq9TcnmZVvIFXllg4HrjVNfQrhQCNwxuBgWBf2DRc4eq6hKzEgyLdlllQFc9ssUFlPD3wOBqoI22r 7N82sI3pqsQYBq5VlKHHreqD8Cq0gictnTFS3IqepASGARKyuCIPDCa4zE76VeQV5zgvkFfjDww C1uZ8PUgjH67DKYqUP9a6euf2v1jUpBrREnm4ZbLAXScDjvrJ11rWYyVXOLZy9nhy9qRBQRvdw tnBThPTmvxaq LAusF8IbvDpZgMrZ3buvThnXuSBGXZxaja7fk/FIlm4RSliDTSGySiizFHy7dJePXuV0c9MI6ciOYxmEIg64NnhBZtB8wipUDJWOpoytOD2/sNQBenjZbYN8291msYnbBG alAOQmEBH5Mn4KyW1VQWE2lBGk9ML SflND8UXfdHz5Q3psOcMZJxSAURKGq5tjA8KlPPOAdQuVPIcysg2/4lV25QGIdDttQVGrkP ZHZcHIPTLLD Vml PJU/OAJGNPGlf3wawUo bID0FKur8N6tNyu7Pnoocn7plDi6WSJgUAaYjI4=
```

at first glance they're the same, but if you check closely, the + gets replaced by a whitespace...

I've even tried switching the + for %2B but on the server-side it gets read as %2B, it isn't converted to a + (flex doesn't seem to function as a browser in this case).

Any kind of insight and help on this matter would be very appreciated.

The requests are being done as follows:

```
public function callService(callback:String, request:String):void{
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(server);
        var requestedString:String = handlePluses(request);
        url.useCache = false;
        url.contentType = contentType;
        url.method = method;
        trace("sending: " + requestedString);
        url.data += requestedString);
        serverURL.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, treatIO);
        serverURL.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        serverURL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadData);   
        serverURL.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, function():void{trace("connected");});
        try{        
            serverURL.load(url);
        }catch(e:ArgumentError){trace("ArgError: " + e.message);}
        catch(e:SecurityError){trace("SecError: " + e.message);}
        catch(e:TimeoutEvent){trace("===========<Timeout>===========");}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we fixed this problem by switching the + character with a subset of escaped characters like `\&\#`.

this might be a problem to others attempting the same thing and trying to keep to a minimum size.